# ListView with data-binding is not displaying the DisplayMember

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a simple program. Whenever I input a value in the textbox and click the Search Button, displays all the rows with the value I search from datatable column. My problem is that it doesn't show the actual value it shows "MyprojectName.MydatatableName". In the list shows all the rows with that value tho, only doesn't show the values.

**Class to acess the values**

```
public class Acesso
{
    public List<Quarto> getDados (string NumAndar)
    {
        IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString("Hotel"));

        var dados = connection.Query<Quarto>($"SELECT * FROM dbo.Quartos WHERE NumAndar = '{NumAndar}'").ToList();
        return dados;
    }
}
```

**ConnectionString Class**

```
 public static class Helper
{
    public static string ConnectionString(string name)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

**Get table values Class**

```
    public class Quarto
{
    public int QuartosID { get; set; }
    public int NumQuarto { get; set; }
    public int NumAndar { get; set; }
    public string TipoQuarto { get; set;}
    public decimal Valor { get; set;}
    public string Disponibilidade { get; set; }
    public bool Manutenção { get; set; }
    public bool Higienização { get; set; }

    public string getAndarNum
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{NumAndar}";
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Quarto> quartos = new List<Quarto>();

    Quarto quarto = new Quarto();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dadosLista.DataSource = quartos;
        dadosLista.DisplayMember = quarto.getAndarNum;
       
    }

    private void btnProcurar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Acesso db = new Acesso();

        quartos = db.getDados(procurarTextBox.Text);

        dadosLista.DataSource = quartos;
        dadosLista.DisplayMember = quarto.getAndarNum;

    }
}
```

Imagine I search number 3. And I have 2 rows with that value

What supose to show:

1. 3
2. 3

What is showing:

1. SQLAprendizagem.Quartos
2. SQLAprendizagem.Quartos

Comment: so: does the data load correctly? if you look at `quartos[0]`, what is `.getAndarNum` ? and what is `.NumAndar`? basically: I'm wondering - is this simply a display problem in `dadosLista`, or has the data actually loaded incorrectly?

Comment: Not related to your question but use a [parameterized query](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/) rather than injecting the literal value into the query string interpolation.

Comment: btw, side notes: 1) connections are disposable, so: you need a `using` for that `connection`; 2) parameters! it *looks* like you're using Dapper, so this should be simple: `var dados = connection.Query<Quarto>("SELECT * FROM dbo.Quartos WHERE NumAndar = @NumAndar", new { NumAndar }).AsList();`

Comment: re the edit: and `"SQLAprendizagem.Quatros"` - that's the fully qualified name of your `Quarto` class, yes? It *sounds* like this is a binding problem in `dadosLista` and it is just defaulting to the object's `ToString()`, which returns the fully qualified type name; so: what is `dadosLista`?

Comment: The data does load correctly but it's not showing that actual value from that row. It shows "MyProjectName.MyTableName"

Comment: dadosList is my listview to display my information

Comment: Yes "SQLAprendizagem.Quartos" is my fully qualified name

Comment: @FabioRodrigues in that case the title "Not getting actual value from SQL Database" is very confusing, as are the tags - this is really just "ListView with data-binding is not displaying the DisplayMember"...? (trying to repro btw, just using the type)

Comment: @MarcGravell I cannot use "using" because of my C# version :(

Comment: @MarcGravello u right, i'll change the tags and title

Comment: @FabioRodrigues `using` has been in C# since C# 1.2 (the very first non-preview release); `using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString("Hotel"))) {...your code here...}`

Comment: @MarcGravell i'll give it a try and tell you the results in a minute

Comment: @MarcGravell But relative to my question what should I do? I'm stuck here in this problem for a long time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```cs
dadosLista.DisplayMember = "getAndarNum"; // or nameof(Quarto.getAndarNum)
```

You are assigning a *value* as the data member *name*, which isn't what it expected. You can also presumably remove the `quarto` field completely.